# Change local user profile programmatically without AD

Tags: c#, .net, directoryservices

I have hit a wall on a project and would appreciate some assistance if any of you were so inclined. I need to take the user "Administrator" and change the username and password. by default the systems that this will work on have the "Administrator" account locked with no password. I found a way to target the existing user but it would appear that I have something wrong when trying to modify the account. the code I currently have is below and look to me as though they should set the values I have not seen this happen.

```
 try
        {
            DirectoryEntry localDir = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
            DirectoryEntries users = localDir.Children;
            DirectoryEntry admin = users.Find("Administrator");

            admin.Username = SAdminUser;
            admin.Password = SAdminPass;
        }
        catch(Exception EX)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(EX.Message);
        }
```

I would appreciate any assistance that I can get with this, I have tried to manually unlock the account then I try to run this and still have not been able to get the values changed. Thank you again for your time and consideration.

Comment: take a look at this article.. are you familiar with DirectoryServices..? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx

Comment: apparently not as much as some. I did see another article and implemented the CommitChanges, and Close lines. unfortunately, this didn't seem to work either.